# How can this happen, file doesn't exist right after checking that it does?

Tags: shell-script, files

I have a shell script that used to work fine on two servers, on one it still seems to work, but on the other it has started to fail several times a day (it runs every hour, and fails 2-8 times a day, quite irregularly).

The logs show that it fails because it tries to move a file that doesn't exist, while debugging more I thought I could stabilise the script a bit by checking that the file exists, before moving it, so now it contains:

```
[ -f .sha1sums.txt ] || exit 0;
mv .sha1sums.txt sha1sums.txt
```

but it still fails several times a day, logging:

```
mv: cannot stat '.sha1sums.txt': No such file or directory
```

(I have checked for weird characters in the script, there are none)

My best guess at how this can happen is currently a race with something else, that removes that file, but I can't see what that would be, so I'm searching for other explanations (or discovery of a typo) and that's where you hopefully come in.

(P.S. The command that produces `.sha1sums.txt`, hasn't failed since I added debug output to show me that 6 days ago)

Comment: Are several copies of that script running in parallel for whatever reason? (or ore there other scripts that are managing that file running in parallel?) Are you sure it's the `mv` command that you show that is generating the error message?

Comment: *a race with something else* - sounds like the only plausible option. Something else could be the same script run twice simultaneously.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Until I found out that the command generating `.sha1sums.txt` didn't fail, I actually thought it might be a timeout in that, that caused the script to run for long enough, that it might race itself. I've mostly abandoned that theory.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I thought that was the only invocation of `mv` in that script, but just to be sure, I just did a search and found another invocation buried in a compound command, in a function, but after careful though, that isn't called with an argument that would cause it to operate on that file.

Comment: The code that you show is the _actual_ code in the script? There are no variables and no globbing patterns etc.?

Comment: Not right there. The `sha1sums.txt` file is fetched (with `curl`) from another  host and might change. The rest of the script then uses both globbing patterns and variables to process the content of `sha1sums.txt` relative to what is in the directory. But in short: yes, this is the *actual* code.